# Is std::this_thread::get_id() reliable in VS2013?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2013

The title says everything:)

```
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::thread threads[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = std::thread([&]()
        {
            printf("thread id = %x\n", std::this_thread::get_id());
            printf("thread id = %x\n", std::this_thread::get_id());
        });
    }

    for (auto& it : threads)
    {
        it.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling and running it using GCC and Clang I have (my) expected result, 4 messages with 2 different values printed in some random order. When using VS2013 I have 4 messages (as expected), but with 4 different values!

Am I doing something wrong here or the compiler/MS threading library?

EDIT: As Tony D pointed out the problem seems to be where I considered thread::id to be an int. Next code works as expected:

```
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::thread threads[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = std::thread([&]()
        {
            std::thread::id id1 = std::this_thread::get_id();
            std::thread::id id2 = std::this_thread::get_id();
            assert(id1 == id2);
        });
    }

    for (auto& it : threads)
    {
        it.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might relate to synchronisation around the output stream.  Why don't you try saving the ids from the two calls into variables, *then* printing them, or equivalently have one printf print both call results?  (Of course there's a race condition, but you'd expect it to be moved to another thread rarely).

Comment: operator<< should be overloaded, so use `std::cout` instead of printf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forcing a [`std::thread::id`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id) into an `int`. Use `std::cout` to write to standard output instead of `printf`. And use some kind of synchronization object:

```
std::mutex display_mutex;

int main()
{
    std::thread threads[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = std::thread([&]()
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> display_lock(display_mutex);
            std::cout << "thread id = " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
            std::cout << "thread id = " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
        });
    }

    for (auto& it : threads)
    {
        it.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But to answer your question: Yes, `std::this_thread::get_id()` is very reliable in VS2013.